# Read words and numbers from text file (c++)

Tags: c++

I have a text with this format:

```
NAME(char) ID(int) MARK(int)
```

for example:

```
JOSH 1234 100
SARA 5678 90
..
..
```

I want to read this file, enter the params to a students struct and then print it on the screen ( you can see in the code).

My problem is that it seems I can't read the name properly, and this line:
`while (file >> id >> word >> grade)` - is getting the `id` and the `mark` correct, but the name in the variable `word` (which is `char *`) is getting hex addresses like 0x000a8520.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct Student
{
    int id;
    char * name = new char [25];
    int mark;
};
int makeStudentsArr(Student * ptr, char * address);
void printArr(Student * ptr, int number);
int main() {
    char * address = new char[26];
    Student * myptr = new Student[50];
    cin >> address;
    int count;
    count = makeStudentsArr(myptr, address);
    printArr(myptr, count);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int makeStudentsArr(Student * ptr, char * address) {
    ifstream file;
    file.open(address);
    char * word = new char[25];
    int id,grade;
    int index = 0;
    while (file >> id >> word >> grade) {
        ptr[index].id = id;
        ptr[index].name = word;
        ptr[index].mark = grade;
        index++;
    }

    return index;
}
void printArr(Student * ptr, int number) {
    for (int i = 0;i < number;i++) {
        cout << "name: " << (ptr + i)->name << " id: " << (ptr + i)->id << " mark: " << (ptr + i)->mark << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `std::string` is good at containing a string of char.  Particularly one that represents text.

Comment: `ptr[index].name = word` copies a pointer but `strcpy(ptr[index].name,word);` copies a string. The first doesn't work because you get the same pointer in all elements of your array. If this makes no sense then you wouldn't be the first newbie to struggle with pointers. Experience programmers use `string` and `vector`, they are easier and more powerful than pointers.

Comment: `name = new char[xx]` <- this is not a string. It is a pointer to 25 consecutive characters on heap. Any assignment you make to that pointer will change it's value and leak your 25 bytes of memory because you will have no way of deleting it. Try reading some book like `accelerated c++` that will teach you the basics of handling strings.

Comment: Don't forget to `delete` that which you `new` when you are done with it. You don't HAVE to put memory back, but sooner or later you'll run out of it. Side note: `char * word = new char[25];` could be `char word[25];` This makes the array an Automatic variable that will be automatically freed for you at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
ptr[index].name = word;
```

to this:

```
strcpy(ptr[index].name, word);
```

since the first copies *the pointer*, while the second copies the actual string (where the pointer is pointing to)!

---

However, your program does not `delete` the memory you dynamically allocated with `new`, which results in memory leaks.

It would be much easier if you used an [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) instead of C strings. Moreover, it would also be easier, if you used an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of plain C arrays.